# How can stream (XML string) be converted to XML in Ballerina 0.990?

Tags: ballerina

Casting support for string to XML was removed in Ballerina 0.990. Is there a safe method to convert XML strings to the xml type in 0.990 and above?

Prior to Ballerina version 0.990, an XML string could be cast to xml type by:

```
string myXMLStream = "<root><foo/></root>";
xml myXML = <xml>myXMLStream;
```

With version 0.990 (and 0.990.1) this results in the error:

> 'string' cannot be explicitly typed as 'xml'

While I have used the following in 0.990.1:

```
string myXMLStream = "<root><foo/></root>";
xml myXML = <xml>`{{myXMLStream}}`;
```

with no compile-time errors, the resulting contents of myXML are unable to be successfully posted as XMLPayloads to an endpoint:

```
http:Request reqProcessXML = new;
reqProcessXML.setXMLPayload(untaint myXML);
var respProcessXML = myEndpoint->post("/myResource",reqProcessXML);
```

This results in the error:

> {ballerina/http}HTTPError {message:"Failed to send outboundRequestMsg to the backend"}

If the XML contents are explicitly created:

```
xml myXML = <xml>`<root><foo/></root>`;
```

the rest of the downstream processing is successful.

Please provide guidance on best/safe practice to convert string to XML with the current version of Ballerina.

Answer (score 3):

You can do as follows.

```
import ballerina/io;

public function main() {
    string myXMLStream = "<root><foo/></root>";
    io:StringReader reader = new io:StringReader(myXMLStream);
    xml|error? myXML = reader.readXml();
    if (myXML is xml) {
        io:println(myXML);
    } else {
        io:println("Something else");
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Manuri. That got it!